# req.checkBody is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm following along with the Mozilla Express tutorial (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms) and have reached the part using express-validator.   When I submit a form whose contents are validated using express-validator I keep getting the error "req.checkBody is not a function" (and if I remove the line that generates that, I get other errors, like "req.sanitize is not a function").  It seems that express-validator is not being recognized properly.  I am using node v6.3.1 for whatever it's worth.

express-validator is installed

```
├── async@2.5.0
├── body-parser@1.17.2
├── cookie-parser@1.4.3
├── debug@2.6.8
├── express@4.15.3
├── express-validator@3.2.0
├── moment@2.18.1
├── mongoose@4.11.0
├── morgan@1.8.2
├── nodemon@1.11.0
├── pug@2.0.0-rc.2
└── serve-favicon@2.4.3
```

I load it in the main app file (app.js)

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
```

and apply it a few lines below that

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator()); // Add this after the bodyParser middlewares!

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and try to make use of it in another module (genreController.js)

```
exports.genre_create_post = function(req, res, next) {

    //Check that the name field is not empty
    req.checkBody('name', 'Genre name required').notEmpty(); 

    //Trim and escape the name field. 
    req.sanitize('name').escape();
    req.sanitize('name').trim();

    //Run the validators
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
```

Where am I going wrong?  I've installed it and de-installed it, I've removed the code from the modules and re-entered it, but to no avail.

```
  req.checkBody is not a function
    TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function
        at exports.genre_create_post (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/controllers/genreController.js:48:9)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at Function.handle (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
        at router (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at /Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
        at next (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
        at Function.handle (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
        at router (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is the way you're using `require` in your code. As you haven't inserted the part of the code that does that I'm assuming a few items. Anyway, you can check a working code and figure out what you've done wrong. OR, paste the whole code here and I'll be able to help you.

try this

```
// index.js

var util = require('util'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser=require('cookie-parser'),
    express = require('express'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(expressValidator()); // this line must be immediately after any of the bodyParser middlewares! 
app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/genres', require('./genre-controller.js').genre_create_post);

app.listen(8888);
```

and `genre-controller.js`

```
// genre-controller.js
exports.genre_create_post = function (req, res, next) {

    console.log('my get method response');

    //Check that the name field is not empty
    req.checkBody('name', 'Genre name required').notEmpty();

    //Trim and escape the name field. 
    req.sanitize('name').escape();
    req.sanitize('name').trim();

    //Run the validators
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    res.end(errors);
};
```

the package.json is

```
{
  "name": "44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

then run

```
$ npm install
$ node index.js
```

and go to `http://localhost:8888/genres` and you'll see the validator working.. the error will be something like this

```
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:549:11)
    at exports.genre_create_post (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/genreController.js:15:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:70:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/projects/44836938-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:445:5
```

Comment: Thanks.  I modified my code with the require order that you had and it didn't help.  You asked to see more code, I'll include more source above -- or should I upload the entire project somewhere?  It's this project: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms -- this is the page I'm up to, and all has been working fine until now…

Comment: I've put the relevant files up on jsfiddle.  I don't know if that helps.  Basically app.js maps routes to "index"  to routes/catalog.js, which routes a request to controllers/genreController which is where the action happens.  I had to put all the files in one jsfiddle, but separated them clearly.  Again, I can upload everything somewhere if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but I don't know why.  If anyone can help me understand it, I'd appreciate the info.  I tracked down the answer when I removed the validator code (just to move on in the project) and then noticed that

```
req.body
```

was `undefined`

Googled an answer for this and it involved moving the routes further down in the setup, so I tried that.

I moved

```
app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/catalog', catalog);  // Add catalog routes to middleware chain.
```

below

```
/ view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(expressValidator()); // Add this after the bodyParser middlewares!
app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I solved it by making sure that in App.js the app.use(expressValidator()) is behind the app.use.bodyParser and I made sure that the routes are after the bodyparser and app.use(express.static......)
I think it has to do with the order in which the elements are put.

In my case the order that seemed to work:

viewengine

BodyParser Middleware

routes

static folder

app.use express validator

Before using this order Checkbody wasn’t present as a function, but  could for instance use function Body. So req. seemed to work but not for all functions.

If ayone can explan better please do :)